# Zeros of a function after a Gaussian convolution

Tags: analysis, roots, convolution, heat-equation

Given an analytic real function $f$ with $n$ zeros, has its Gaussian convolution at most $n$ zeros?

Comment: Are you assuming decay properties on $f$? The convolution might not even be defined.

Comment: I am also quite perplexed by the hypothesis of analyticity. I think continuous and $L^1$ could be enough.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have found this result with these hypothesis, but the proof is a bit strange

Comment: How does it rely on analyticity? Could you share a link?

Comment: https://archive.org/details/zerocrossingshea00humm/mode/2up (Theorem 2.1). I understand the key idea (maybe using another formulation of maximum principle would be better), but I think it is possible to find a proof with simpler arguments.

Comment: From what I understood: they don’t require $f$ analytic, they only say that the locus of the zeros the solution to the heat equation can be parametrized analytically, since it is a smooth function. Moreover, they require $f$ bounded. The complications come from $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is much easier to do a proof for the case you are thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. The reason is that the gaussian kernel is a Polya frequency function. Then, the convolution has a variation diminishing property.